# Row,column line of table not visible in IE

Tags: asp.net, css

```
  <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" align="center" rules="all" class="ContentTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Active Students
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtActiveStudents" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Student/Teacher Ratio (Agreed Upon)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRatio" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

here is css

```
 .ContentTable
 {
border: solid 1px #EBEBEB;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 98%;
vertical-align: middle;

  }
```

My problem is the table style not applied.

I want the table to be formated as rows and columns(borders).

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by " I want the table to be formated as rows and columns"?

Comment: I see borders showing up on IE10.

Comment: Where is this CSS ? is it defined inline or it's an external file?

Comment: I see border is missing around the table, though appearing on tr and td. Actually it is the other way round (The color chosen is too light). Table has the border and it is more visible on rows and cols because top & bottom row borders contributing to this and making it more appealing. Just change your style name from .ContentTable to .ContentTable, .ContentTable tr, .ContentTable td and see if your problem gets solved.

Comment: [try this (I can't test in ie 8)](http://jsfiddle.net/T2HUg/1/) if that doesn't work then [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/T2HUg/3/)

Comment: Your code works for me.  Make sure you have correct reference to CSS. I am using IE8

Comment: @Pete if change like that it was not working in other browsers

Comment: @Kaylan - [ie only stylesheet](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) (lots of sites use them cos IE is so crap)